# Office 365 API / delegate and login

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I have read a lot of articles about Office 365 API but I need additionnals informations. My goal (MVC Projet) is to collect some data (read only) of my tenant (and customers tenants) like licences subscription (like csp), user informations (like affected , affected licenses), ...
I think to use Microsoft Graph .Net Library.

1. Is it possible to interact by the api with tenant of my client (I'm Office 365 Partners) by login in my tenant (as the delegate permission in the admin portal) ?
2. Is it possible to have only an application authentication without requierd an additionnal MS account to login to the api.

Thanks for help,
Regards,
Yannick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the CSP/partner model to call Microsoft Graph (and either have your app pre-consented for application permissions/auth OR for your Agents to log in using delegated admin privileges to your customer tenants) is NOT yet supported, but is coming soon.

Please take a look at https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph for what is supported (Directory features) in Microsoft Graph.  This article was updated very recently.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to access to the MS Graph Preview Version.  Partner admin on behalf of capability (for resellers and syndicators who are part of the Cloud Solution Provider program) is mentionned as Coming soon (preview). Thanks

Comment: Yes - it'll be in preview soon. I'll post back when it's available.

Comment: Hey @DanKershaw-MSFT, what is the status of this please? Also your link is dead - https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph ("dev.office.com’s server IP address could not be found")

Comment: Wow this is old.  Yes this is available:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-cloudsolutionprovider